# NullPointerException on Progress Dialog while exporting to CSV - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, export-to-csv, progressdialog

I get null pointer exception on context no matter how I modify pre-execute class or the declaration of ProgressBar.I have tried several solutions that others implemented to fix the error, but nothing works.

My app should export CSV upon the button click in CatalogActivity.

Spent few days on this already...Your help is much appreciated.

CatalogActivity:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                //export data to CSV using method in InventoryProvider via separate java class ExportDatabaseCSVTask
            case  R.id.export_to_csv:
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

                    new ExportDatabaseCSVTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

                } else {

                    new ExportDatabaseCSVTask().execute("");
                }
```

ExportDatabaseCSVTask:

```
public class ExportDatabaseCSVTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {


    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    InventoryProvider iProvider;



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);  ---ERROR HERE

        this.dialog.setMessage("Saving. Please Wait...");
       this.dialog.show();
    }



    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

        File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/codesss/");
        if (!exportDir.exists()) { exportDir.mkdirs(); }

        File file = new File(exportDir, "inventory.csv");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            Cursor curCSV = iProvider.raw(CONTENT_URI);
            csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());
            while(curCSV.moveToNext()) {
                String arrStr[]=null;
                String[] mySecondStringArray = new String[curCSV.getColumnNames().length];
                for(int i=0;i<curCSV.getColumnNames().length;i++)
                {
                    mySecondStringArray[i] =curCSV.getString(i);
                }
                csvWrite.writeNext(mySecondStringArray);
            }
            csvWrite.close();
            curCSV.close();
            return true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) { this.dialog.dismiss(); }
        if (success) {
            Toast.makeText(CatalogActivity.getApplicationContext, "this is my Toast message!!! =)",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ShareFile();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(CatalogActivity.getApplicationContext, "Export failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void ShareFile() {
        File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/codesss/");
        String fileName = "myfile.csv";
        File sharingGifFile = new File(exportDir, fileName);
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("application/csv");
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(sharingGifFile);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        CatalogActivity.getApplicationContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share CSV"));
    }
```

Logcat:

2019-03-02 21:05:16.109 7122-7122/com.example.android.name E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.stockpile, PID: 7122
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:224)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.(AlertDialog.java:201)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.(AlertDialog.java:197)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.(AlertDialog.java:142)
        at android.app.ProgressDialog.(ProgressDialog.java:94)
        at com.example.android.stockpile.ExportDatabaseCSVTask.onPreExecute(ExportDatabaseCSVTask.java:40)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:648)
        at com.example.android.stockpile.CatalogActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(CatalogActivity.java:199)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3435)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:436)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:196)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:888)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:981)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:625)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:151)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
2019-03-02 21:05:16.114 1694-4875/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.android.name/.CatalogActivity

If I try to add below to ExportDatabaseCSVTask:

```
public ExportDatabaseCSVTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
```

I get the following error in CatalogActivity:

```
 case  R.id.export_to_csv:
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

                    new ExportDatabaseCSVTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR); - ERROR

                } else {

                    new ExportDatabaseCSVTask().execute(""); --ERROR
                }
```

error: 
constructor ExportDatabaseCSVTask in class ExportDatabaseCSVTask cannot be applied to given types;
                    new ExportDatabaseCSVTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                    ^
  required: Context
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
F:\Android projects\Stockpile\app\src\main\java\com\example\android\stockpile\CatalogActivity.java:203: error: constructor ExportDatabaseCSVTask in class ExportDatabaseCSVTask cannot be applied to given types;
                    new ExportDatabaseCSVTask().execute("");
                    ^
  required: Context
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your context will be always null, because he's no initialised. Initialise context via constructor

```
private Context context;

public ExportDatabaseCSVTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

This an example how to call after added constructor:

```
new ExportDatabaseCSVTask(this)
```

Also be careful with passing context inside ExportDatabaseCSVTask class, better wrap context via WeakReference.

Comment: Hi Dmitro, thank you for the reply! I have tried this before and now too, and the error I receive is: "
  required: Context
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

Comment: basically, i need to modify reference in CatalogActivity's onOptionsItemSelected. However, I don't know how else to refer to ExportDatabaseCSVTask....

Comment: I edited my answer, see how your could call your AsyncTask. Nothing special, just pass your context.

Comment: thank you Dmitro, now there is no error finally! I will vote the answer :) Now I have a new issue, probably i need to create a new question? As I click on my Export button, nothing happens - no message pops up or action to save the file: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 3650731 , only wrote 3650400

Comment: Yes, better create a new issue.